# how to write a crossover function for genetic algorithm

Tags: python, pytorch, genetic-algorithm

```
def crossover(parents):
    result = copy.deepcopy(parents[0].brain)
    for param in result.parameters():
        print((param.shape[0] / 2))
        if len(param.shape) == 2:  # weights of linear layer
            for i0 in range(param.shape[0]):
                for i1 in range(param.shape[1]):
                    if i0 < (param.shape[0] / 2) and i1 < (param.shape[1]):
                        param[i0][i1] = [param[i0][i1] for param in parents[0].brain.parameters() if
                                         len(param.shape) == 2]
                        # print("x is", x)
                        # print(f"param{i0}{i1}", param[i0][i1])
                        # param[i0][i1] = 2
                    else:
                        param[i0][i1] = [param[i0][i1] for param in parents[1].brain.parameters() if
                                         len(param.shape) == 2]
```

I am using pytorch library and trying to write a crossover function for my project. initially for the crossover result i just copied the brain of the one of the parents for the ease. then I'm cutting it from the middle and the merging the brains of both of the parents in it. The problem is the output of this "param[i0][i1] for param in parents[1].brain.parameters()" comes out to be a list of 3 tensors which shouldn't.
output

```
x is [tensor(0.0775), tensor(0.0372), tensor(0.2628)]
param07 tensor(0.0775)
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Can you give a simple input/out example? Your definition of the problem is not clear.

Comment: input/output as in the structure of brain you mean?

Comment: You mentioned, `The problem is the output of this "param[i0][i1] for param in parents[1].brain.parameters()" comes out to be a list of 3 tensors which shouldn't.`. What is the expected output then? Try to define your problem in simpler words.

Comment: both of them have a same input of tensor shape(16,24). while the same for loop applied to one yields only one tensor and where as the other produces a list of 3 tensors. i only want one tensor like tensor(0.0775).

Comment: something is wrong with the list comprehension i used there

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with the list comprehension i tried to use there which i think i don't understand completely still. so i wrote a proper loop for it and it worked.

```
def crossover(parents):
    result = copy.deepcopy(parents[0].brain)
    for param in result.parameters():
        if len(param.shape) == 2:  # weights of linear layer
            for i0 in range(param.shape[0]):
                for i1 in range(param.shape[1]):
                    if i0 < (param.shape[0] / 2) and i1 < (param.shape[1]):
                        for p in parents[0].brain.parameters():
                            if len(p.shape) == 2 and param.shape == p.shape:
                                param[i0][i1] = p[i0][i1]
                    else:
                        for p in parents[1].brain.parameters():
                            if len(p.shape) == 2 and param.shape == p.shape:
                                param[i0][i1] = p[i0][i1]
```